# Using 'go build' fetches dependencies even though they are in vendor/

Tags: go, go-modules

I am trying to fetch a Go project and copy the dependencies under the `vendor/` directory so I have the complete source code of the project and its dependencies in my project. However, even after doing that, deleting the packages under `$GOPATH/pkg/mod` and rebuilding cause the Go compiler to re-fetch all dependencies, which takes a considerable of time.

This is what I did:

```sh
# Fetch the project, e.g. influx/telegraf
go get -d github.com/influxdata/telegraf

# CD into the project
cd $GOPATH/src/influxdata/telegraf

# Fetch the modules under vendor/ directory
go mod vendor
```

After calling the last command, Go will fetch all the dependencies under `pkg/mod`. Not sure why it is doing that, but I assume it is because it needs to build the project normally, and then move the fetched dependencies under the `vendor/` folder. After that, I can build successfully. However, to make sure I no longer require those dependencies, I deleted the `pkg/mod` directory completely and rebuilt the project. Go compiler, for some reason, fetched the packages again.

Is there anything I am doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `vendor` folder is not used automatically in all cases.

To make sure dependencies are loaded from the main module's vendor folder, pass `-mod=vendor` to the go tool.

The `vendor` folder if present is only used automatically (if not specified otherwise with `-mod=mod`) if the go version specified by `go.mod` file is `1.14` or higher.

These are detailed in [Command go: Maintaining module requirements](https://golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-Maintaining_module_requirements):

> If invoked with -mod=vendor, the go command loads packages from the main module's vendor directory instead of downloading modules to and loading packages from the module cache. The go command assumes the vendor directory holds correct copies of dependencies, and it does not compute the set of required module versions from go.mod files. However, the go command does check that vendor/modules.txt (generated by 'go mod vendor') contains metadata consistent with go.mod.
>
> If invoked with -mod=mod, the go command loads modules from the module cache even if there is a vendor directory present.
>
> If the go command is not invoked with a -mod flag and the vendor directory is present and the "go" version in go.mod is 1.14 or higher, the go command will act as if it were invoked with -mod=vendor.

Comment: Thanks, this is informing. It did work for me on my Linux desktop. However, on macOS I got the following error when using the vendored packages which doesn't happen otherwise:

# github.com/shirou/gopsutil/host
vendor/github.com/shirou/gopsutil/host/host_darwin_cgo.go:9:11: fatal error: 'include/smc.c' file not found

. Any idea?

Comment: @Rafid That error seems to be cgo (not go code) related.

Comment: Yeah, I found an issue about it: https://github.com/shirou/gopsutil/issues/491 . It is interesting, though, that it doesn't show up until I vendor the packages. It seems to me that it could be a versioning problem, causing the vendored module version to be different than what is used without vendoring.

Comment: OK, I found out what the issue is. `go mod vendor` is doing some pruning that causes the `smc.c` file and some other files to disappear from the vendored code: https://github.com/golang/go/issues/26366 . The suggestion I got is to manually copy those files for now: https://github.com/shirou/gopsutil/issues/832#issuecomment-627244083 . It is not ideal, but I will have to live with it for now.

Comment: @Rafid Thanks for sharing.

Comment: No problem. I also created an SO question and answer for this particular issue since I didn't find a similar issue on SO: https://stackoverflow.com/q/62705020