# Using `shirou/gopsutil` Go package as a vendored package fails on macOS (10.14.6)

Tags: go, telegraf, govendor

I was trying to build `influx/telegraf` locally and vendor all the packages using `go mod vendor` command. However, interestingly, the build fails after that with the following error:

```
# github.com/shirou/gopsutil/host
vendor/github.com/shirou/gopsutil/host/host_darwin_cgo.go:9:11: fatal error: 'include/smc.c' file not found
 #include "include/smc.c"
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Steps to reproduce (after setting GOPATH variable):

```sh
# Fetch the project, e.g. influx/telegraf
go get -d github.com/influxdata/telegraf

# CD into the project
cd $GOPATH/src/influxdata/telegraf

# Checkout v1.14.5 (the current latest version)
git checkout v1.14.5

# Fetch the modules under vendor/ directory
go mod vendor

# Then modify the Makefile as follows:
# 1. Remove the `deps` target and its reference in the `all` target; it is not needed anymore, as we fetched all modules.
# 2. Add the `-mod vendor` flag everywhere `go build`, `go install`, or `go test` is called. This is necessary since Telegraf v1.14.5 is still on version 1.12 of Go, which requires this flag to use the modules under `vendor/` directory.

# Finally, build the project and you should get the error above
make
```

Answer (score 3):

It turned out that this error is caused by a well known issue whereby `go mod vendor` prunes non-package directories, hence causing the `host/include` folder of `shirou/gopsutil`, which contains the `smc.c` file, to be pruned:

https://github.com/golang/go/issues/26366

The impact of this issue on `shirou/gopsutil` is already reported:

https://github.com/shirou/gopsutil/issues/832

There is no easy solution apparently, but a work-around for now is to manually copy the missing directories to `vendor/github.com/shirou/gopsutil`. In my case, I copied `freebsd_headers` and `include` from `$GOPATH/pkg/mod/github.com/shirou/gopsutil/host` to `$GOPATH/src/github.com/influxdata/telegraf/vendor/github.com/shirou/gopsutil` and it worked.

I hope you find this helpful.

Comment: This was fixed with https://github.com/shirou/gopsutil/pull/889 being merged, no workaround is needed nowadays.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @Rafid, you can do a manual copy.
I found this below work-around to be helpful as well.

Run these commands

```
go get github.com/shirou/gopsutil
go mod vendor
```